# Is it possible to load a file with JS/HTML5 FileReader from filename without input file?

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

I want to change an `<article>` element content with another html file content but searching I found it's not possible with JS load function because of Chrome security with local files.

Another case I tried was including `<embed>` or `<object>` elements, but with those I can't control the height dynamically, only in a static way with 'height' attribute.

Finally, I found `FileReader utility`, but I've only watched it using an `<input type="file">` element.

How can I load an Html File only with the file name?

```
// No input needed, I know what I want to read
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAstext( "anotherpage.html", "UTF-8" );
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : path + name + '.html',
    dataType : "text",
    success : function(data) {
        // TODO success, for example
        $(articleSelector).html(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible.
In the client-side JavaScript,it's forbidden to read files in the disk directly.Even in the Chrome Extension(https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/index.html), you can hardly get the permission.You can think it's a security policy.